# Parameters of a Java generic method

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to figure out the whole Java generics topic.

More specifically this issue:

```
public class Node<E>{
    private E data;
    public Node(E data){
        this.data=data;
    }
    public E get(){
        return this.data;
    }
    public void set(E data){
        this.data=data;
    }
}
```

How can I add an "extends" wildcard specifying that the *set* method can receive E **or** any inheriting class of E (in which case the Node will hold a upcasted version of the parameter).

Or will it work even if I leave it the way it is?

(I might be a bit confused with the invariant aspect of generic types.)

Thanks!

Comment: It will already do what you want...

Comment: I downvoted the question. It is easily answerable if you do a tiny bit of work yourself. You don't even need google, just use ctrl-space in any Java IDE and see for yourself.

Comment: @Dariusz You're free to do whatever you wish. 
The thing is, sometimes code will "work" even if you don't really know why or how well it works. 
That's why I asked here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class is already doing what you require. Lets demonstrate by example. Lets say you have created Node (`Number` is super class of `Integer`, `Long` etc);

```
Node<Number> numberNode = new Node<Number>(1);
```

You can call set method by passing its subclasses also

```
numberNode.set(new Integer(1));
numberNode.set(new Long(1));
```

Answer (score 3):

You declared your class  `Node<E>`  where it already accepts any inheriting class of `E`.

Comment: is this different with passing collections as generics? Because when we write `someMethod(ArrayList<E>)` then only arrayLists with type `E` can be passed.

Comment: @PrasadKharkar Good spotted! Yes they are different.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
public void set(E extends SomeType){
 this.data=data;
 }
```

then you can pass any object that `implements or extends SomeType`
Remeber that `SomeType` can also be an `interface` here, even if it is strange, we need to write `E extends SomeType`.

Answer (score 0):

> Or will it work...?

Or have you **[tried it out if it works](http://ideone.com/AQCttT)**?

```
        final Node<Number> n =  new Node<Number>(new Integer(666));
        System.out.println(n.get());
        n.set(new Integer(777));
        System.out.println(n.get());
```